# Mysql convert few columns into one row

Tags: mysql

I have something like this:

```
id  | month | col |  col2
--------------------------
101 |  Jan  |   A  |  B    
102 |  feb  |   C  |  A    
102 |  feb  |   D  |  Q
```

And i need something like this:

```
id  | month |  col  |  col2
----------------------------
101 |  Jan  |  A    |  B    
102 |  feb  |  C,D  |  A,Q
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the desired output, you'll want to look into [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT
    id, month,
    GROUP_CONCAT(col) AS col,
    GROUP_CONCAT(col2) AS col2
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    id, month;
```